# How do you remove Gerrit's REST API's magic prefix in the response body with Groovy code?

Tags: json, rest, groovy, gerrit

My code:

```
@Grab('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7')
@Grab('oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2')
@Grab('oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2')
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*

def gerrit = new RESTClient('http://localhost:8080/gerrit')
gerrit.auth.basic "gerrit", "password123"
gerrit.get( path: 'changes/1234/reviewers' )
```

As per https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html#authentication

"To prevent against Cross Site Script Inclusion (XSSI) attacks, **the JSON response body starts with a magic prefix line that must be stripped before feeding the rest of the response body to a JSON parse**r:"

```
  )]}'
  [ ... valid JSON ... ]
```

My error:

```
WARNING: Error parsing 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' response
groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

The current character read is ')' with an int value of 41
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 0
)]}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
@Grab('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7')
@Grab('oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2')
@Grab('oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:1.2.1.2')
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

public class GerritRestClient {
    def gerrit

    GerritRestClient(config) {
        def username = config.username
        def password = config.password
        this.gerrit = new RESTClient(config.endpoint)
        this.gerrit.auth.basic config.username, config.password
    }

  def sendRequest(path) {
    this.gerrit.request(GET,TEXT) { req ->
      uri.path = path // overrides any path in the default URL
      response.success = { resp, json ->
        assert resp.status == 200
        def fixedJson = json.text.replaceAll('\\)]}\'', '').trim() // remove magic prefix
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        return jsonSlurper.parseText(fixedJson) // parse the fixed json body and return
      }
      // called only for a 404 (not found) status code:
      response.failure = { resp ->
        println "My response handler got response: ${resp.statusLine}"
        return null
      }
    }
  }

  def getChangeReviewers(changeNumber) {
    def requestPath = "changes/${changeNumber}/reviewers"
    return sendRequest(requestPath)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm not very familiar with Groovy, but there is no way to remove this prefix from Gerrit unless you want to modify the source code and roll your own release.

The solution is to use a different Groovy API to get the raw data, strip off the first 5 characters, and then feed this into the Groovy JSON parser.  Again, sorry, but I can't help out with what Groovy API might be an option.

As the docs mention, these characters are annoying at times, but an important security feature of Gerrit to prevent any XSS hacks.

Comment: Thanks! I've used the same Groovy API Rest client, it just needs to be done differently.